# What is the usage of 3rd lead in mobile batteries

Tags: battery-charging, mobile, pinout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why we have 3 pins on some batteries?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/10588/why-we-have-3-pins-on-some-batteries)

I'm trying to build (DIY) open charger for mobile battery. I would like to know what is the usage the middle one?

[image]

Is there anyway I could check the status of battery (i.e., charged to max)?

Comment: Duplicate of [http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/10588/why-we-have-3-pins-on-some-batteries](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/10588/why-we-have-3-pins-on-some-batteries) ?