# Using Arduino to power a 4 terminal phone

Tags: arduino, voltage, batteries, cellphone

My dad took my battery for misbehaving (No questions!) but I still want to use my phone (Huawei Honor 3c). However, when I use a USB plug, the phone only vibrates constantly (Why does it do this?).

So I looked around and found my Arduino(Uno) and thought I could turn my phone on with this.

However, I found a few problems. (BTW, all info in this image http://vifocal.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/38c4fbe4447791bfb2ff7ebb56cba1e8/h/u/huawei3c_1.jpg)

1) There were 4 terminals. 2 marked with + and - (What are the other 2?)

2) Battery outputs 3.8V while my Arduino has 5V and 3.3V (Which to use?)

3) Is it even possible to try such thing (Could it work?)

Comment: Before we can answer, we need to know: Have you stopped misbehaving?

Comment: Question 1) has been [asked before](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/101118/7036).  Here's an [answer](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/27700/7036).

Comment: @NickAlexeev Wait, what does SDA and SCL stand for

Comment: Don't try it. If the battery outputs 3.8V you need a 3.8V source. There are many other limitations as well. Just wait until you get your battery back. If you find another way to power your phone, make sure that it has the same specs of the battery. If you undertake this(you must really want to use your phone if you are thinking about powering it with an arduino), just know that there is a big risk. You may break your phone.

Comment: I found out another way to power my phone. Use my brothers battery. Its not the same size but who cares

Comment: You rogue... Imma tell your father !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IF** you had a proper bench power supply, you **could** *just provide power*. You could simply dial in the voltage (and current limit) and try connecting to your phone.

But even if you could do that, the phone may refuse to play unless it can "talk" to the battery through those other two terminals. Many devices like that need to know WHO the battery is, and WHAT its current condition is. And if you can't simulate that, you are out of luck even with the correct voltage and current.

Answer (score 0):

In case you've stopped misbehaving..here's something: Arduino cannot help you to run your phone ANYHOW. Simplest thing to do would be to get a bench power supply and do some fine wiring to the phone. Best would be to check what those pins are for (on phone too), maybe you need just to hook some together (although it's very small % of possibilities for doing that).

Comment: Cant I just provide power?

Comment: I don't think you understand the nor definition of power nor use of Arduino.
Definition of power is voltage * currect, which means, you should produce both for power suppling the phone.
You technically "can provide power" from arduino, but be sure it won't be enough.
Arduinos are microcontrollers, which are ment to deal with input/output devices (such as sensors and motors), not to be used as power supply to something so "greedy" as is cell phone.
You more than arduino need a bench power supply.
As I've said before, check the datasheet of phone and find out, what those pins are.