# lithium ion battery capacity loss across different storage charge levels over time

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion

We can see this [simple chart](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/150832/3039) in many places, however I am curious to know how the numbers work out for different starting charge levels than 40% (3.8V, ish? for li-ion).

For example, how much worse is 10% charge level than 40% charge level? Importantly, is it preferable to leave a battery charged at 100% or at 10% (as these are usually the states that we find cells charged to)?

Comment: Factories usually ship at 60% SoC for max room temp life

Comment: What do you mean "how much worse is ..."? Worse than what?

Comment: @AliChen worse than 40%. E.g.: 40% starting charge, after one year @ 25C, 4% is lost. *What if starting charge is 10%?* How much total capacity is lost after one year??

Comment: 100% is not good for the battery. It will last longer if stored at lower SOC. The danger with low SOC levels is that the battery may become deeply discharged.

Comment: What I mean is, I don't think 10% is bad for the battery. But the battery protection circuit or BMS consumes some current, and there is also self-discharge. So if a battery is kept at 10%, and sits for many months, it may become deeply discharged (for example below 2.7V) which is generally considered bad.

Comment: Actually I think factories have to go down to 40% now due to shipping regulations. I am not 100% sure, but that is what I remember from talking to our operations guys where I work.